# why this xsl writes text out of nodes

Tags: .net, xslt

Into xsl file i declare a template for the Prov Element. The xml source contains also a Doc Element, but there's no template for this element.

why xsl transofmation writes some inner text from the Doc element?

hi, this is xml input

```
<Root>
  <Doc attr1="1" attr2="2" attr3="3">
    <node1 attr1="1" />
    <node2 attr1="2" />
    <node3 attr1="3" />
    <node4>1900-01-01T00:00:00Z</node4>
    <node5>1900-01-01T00:00:00Z</node5>
    <node6>
      <node7>
        <node8>xxx</node8>
        <node9>yyyy</node9>
        <node10>zzz</node10>
      </node7>
    </node6>
    <node11>xxx</node11>
    <node12>yyy</node12>
  </Doc>
  <Prov attr1="1" attr2="2" attr3="3" />
</Root>
```

i need this output:

```
<Prov attr1="1" attr2="2" />
```

this is xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"  />
  <xsl:template match="Prov" >
    <xsl:element name="Prov">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@attr1" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="@attr2" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is actual output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>




        1900-01-01T00:00:00Z
        1900-01-01T00:00:00Z


            xxx
            yyyy
            zzz


        xxx
        yyy

      <Prov attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for what you see are the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#built-in-rule). You only have a template matching `Prov`. That leaves the entire `Doc` branch of your input XML to be processed by these built-in templates, that copy all text nodes to the output.

To prevent this, you could add:

```
<xsl:template match="/Root" >
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Prov"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to your stylesheet, or - if you prefer - shorten the whole thing to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root" >
    <Prov attr1="{Prov/@attr1}" attr2="{Prov/@attr2}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```